# How to I change my react table accesssor value based on data conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-table, mui-datatable

```
const data = {
    name:"test1",
    fclPrice:100,
    lclPrice:null,
    total:"50"
    }
```

and my two columns:

```
const Datatable = [
  { Header: 'Name', accessor: 'name' }, 
  { Header: 'Price', accessor:'?' },
  { Header: 'Total', accessor:'total' }  
];
```

I want accessor to take the price key which has number
For eg : if fclprice:null and lclPrice:100 it should take lclPrice and viceversa

Comment: Better to map your data to conform to the condition, especially if you'll have multiple objects of that shape as you'd need to change the `accessor` per entry. `const tableData = {...data, price: data.fclPrice ?? data.lclPrice};` and then acessor is just `'price'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a set a value of an accessor to a [function](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options) which will take as a first argument the object with your data. Then, you can pass whatever condition you want to it:

```
const Datatable = [
  { Header: 'Price', accessor: (data)=>data.fclPrice || data.lclPrice},  
];
```